# ASPxGridview Edit From

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, aspxgridview

I'm trying to change the values of some of the controls in the ASPxGridview Edit Form, however they are not changing. It seems to be resetting?

How can I do this and in which event would I do this in?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: What tech.  do you use for editing values? SqlDataAdapter or ObjectDataSource or ?

Comment: The controls I am trying to change are not binded to any datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your datasoruce which you bind to grid view with that and then you try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe,

I've made a screencast that walks you through the common data editing scenarios of the ASPxGridView. Check it out here:

[ASPxGridView Data Editing 101](http://tv.devexpress.com/#ASPxGridView101DataEditing.movie)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Columns of ASPxGridView must be bind with some DataSource to enable edition feature. Otherwise they will be read only.

[]'s